# Set new edge capacity

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, properties

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

I am trying to add a new edge to an existing graph and set its capacity, but for some reason the `SetProperty` call is not evaluated. A minimal example:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, EdgeCapacity -> {10, 20}];
gt = EdgeAdd[g, 1 -> 3];
gt = SetProperty[{gt, 1 -> 3}, EdgeCapacity -> 10]

(* Out: SetProperty[{*graph with new edge pic*, 1 -> 3}, EdgeCapacity -> 10]*)
```

However, if I call `SetProperty` with `EdgeWeight` or `EdgeLabels` instead, it works fine. What is the proper way to set a new edge capacity?

I am using version 10.3.0.

Comment: This looks buggish to me; when I try `PropertyValue[gt, EdgeCapacity]` instead of `SetProperty`, I get a message saying part 3 of {1,3} does not exist, instead of `$Failed`.

Comment: I agree, looks very buggy! It works for some reason if you don't set any edge capacities in `g`.

Comment: Yes. The only workaround I can think of is extracting the entire sets of vertices and edges with all their properties from an old graph, adding a new edge to the edge set, a new capacity to the capacity set, and creating a new graph from all of this from scratch.

Comment: Same results on V9. Tagging as a bug

Comment: Please do report this problem to Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, just an analysis of the problem.

[Mathematica stores different edge properties in different ways.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118196/12)

`EdgeWeight`, `EdgeCost` and `EdgeCapacity` seem to be stored as a plain list of numbers, set in a separate option of `Graph`. They are all affected by this problem.

What happens when using `EdgeAdd` is that this list is not amended:

```
gt // InputForm

Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[2, 3], DirectedEdge[1, 3]}, 
 {EdgeCapacity -> {10, 20}}]
```

It still has length 2, even though the graph now has three vertices.

I would have expected `EdgeCapacity -> {10, 20, 1}`, as `1` is the default value of this property.

This way `EdgeAdd` essentially corrupts the internal structure of the `Graph` and makes it unsafe to use.  All sorts of unexpected things may happen when trying to use weighted graph functions on it (typically they just don't evaluate).