# Are list-valued vertex weights in graphs invalid?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The [documentation for VertexWeight](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexWeight.html) clearly states:

> The weight ***w<sub>i</sub>*** can be any expression.

But I cannot seem to set list-valued vertex weights in my graph:

```
Graph[
    {"A", "B", "C"},
    Map[Apply[UndirectedEdge], {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}}],
    VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3}
] // GraphQ
(* True *)

Graph[
    {"A", "B", "C"},
    Map[Apply[UndirectedEdge], {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}}],
    VertexWeight -> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}
] // GraphQ
(* False *)
```

Is this a bug, or do I have a syntax error somewhere? (I am using Mathematica 13.0 on Windows 11 Pro.)

Comment: This does go against the documentation so it is worth reporting to WRI, but also you should find a workaround.  Is there a reason you are storing the lists as weights rather than some other property?  You could store them as a custom property with something like ```g = Graph[{"A", "B", "C"}, {"A" <-> "B",  "A" <-> "C"},  AnnotationRules -> {"A" -> {"vertwt" -> {1, 2}}, 
    "B" -> {"vertwt" -> {3, 4}}, "C" -> {"vertwt" -> {4, 5}}}]``` and access them via something like `AnnotationValue[{g, "A"}, "vertwt"]`

Comment: @JasonB. thanks for the confirmation. I will report this as a bug to WRI. Yes, I can certainly use the workaround mentioned in your comment. (As to the reason: I am designing a custom graph neural network to operate on the molecular library with which you are already so intimately familiar.)

Comment: @Shredderroy you could store integer edge weights in the graph and then use them as keys into an Association which contains the lists / matrices etc.

Comment: `VertexWeight` is special, and seems to be optimized for storing numerical values. It can be accessed _much_ faster than other properties. Unfortunately, these quirks of the property system are not documented. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118196/12